# value present with specific value exclude from output

Tags: sql

```
SKU VCODE   rollover
140053, M11 ,   STONE
140053, M11 ,   REC
TCI950600,  T16  ,  REC
PSR1400600303,  P2J ,   STONE
BUS14007,   L22 ,   NIT
BUS14007,   L22  ,  STONE
TLS1400E,   TSP  ,  RECFIT
BOR140120,  B25  ,  STONE
BOR140120,  B25  ,  REC
```

If same SKU Present with `ROLLOVER ='STONE'` and `'REC'` both,  or if SKU present only with `ROLLOVER ='REC'`, then exclude from output

Output should be

```
SKU VCODE   rollover
PSR1400600303,  P2J  ,  STONE
BUS14007,   L22 ,   NIT
BUS14007,   L22,    STONE
TLS1400E,   TSP,    RECFIT
```

Comment: Provide your dbms, query, what you have tried?

Comment: will `BOR140120` be included in output if another row for `rollover ='RECFIT'` was added?

Comment: Hello ughai. No . REC will only be available with stone or REC alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic implementation would be:

```
select SKU, VCODE, ROLLOVER
  from YOUR_TABLE ot
  where not exists (
     select 1
       from YOUR_TABLE it
       where it.ROLLOVER = 'REC'
         and it.SKU = ot.SKU
  )
```

Here "where no SKUs with ROLLOVER ='STONE' or 'REC'" is covered with more generic condition "where no SKUs with ROLLOVER = 'REC'".

There may be more efficient implementation options but these depend on features certain DBMS provide.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. but i am getting error. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.. Please help

Comment: The `outer` seems to be recognized as a reserved word by the parser. Changed the answer to avoid such collisions.